# How can I change this function to be compatible with Python 2 and Python 3? I'm running into string, unicode and other problems

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x, unicode, bytecode

I have a function that is designed to make some text safe for filenames or URLs. I'm trying to change it so that it works in Python 2 and Python 3. In my attempt, I've confused myself with bytecode and would welcome some guidance. I'm encountering errors like `sequence item 1: expected a bytes-like object, str found`.

```
def slugify(
    text       = None,
    filename   = True,
    URL        = False,
    return_str = True
    ):

    if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):

        # insert magic here

    else:

        if type(text) is not unicode:
            text = unicode(text, "utf-8")
        if filename and not URL:
            text = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", text).encode("ascii", "ignore")
            text = unicode(re.sub("[^\w\s-]", "", text).strip())
            text = unicode(re.sub("[\s]+", "_", text))
        elif URL:
            text = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", text).encode("ascii", "ignore")
            text = unicode(re.sub("[^\w\s-]", "", text).strip().lower())
            text = unicode(re.sub("[-\s]+", "-", text))
        if return_str:
            text = str(text)

    return text
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your main problem is figuring out how to convert the text to unicode and back to bytes when you aren't sure what the original type was. In fact, you can do this without any conditional checks if you're careful.

```
if isinstance(s, bytes):
    s = s.decode('utf8')
```

Should be sufficient to convert something to unicode in either Python 2 or 3 (assuming 2.6+ and 3.2+ as is usual). This is because bytes exists as an alias for string in Python 2. The explicit `utf8` argument is only required in Python 2, but there's no harm in providing it in Python 3 as well. Then to convert back to a bytestring, you just do the reverse.

```
if not isinstance(s, bytes):
    s = s.encode('utf8')
```

Of course, I would recommend that you think hard about why you are unsure what types your strings have in the first place. It is better to keep the distinction seperate, rather than write "weak" APIs that accept either. Python 3 just encourages you to maintain the separation.

Comment: `not isinstance(s, bytes)` will always be true.  Did you mean to assign `s.decode('utf-8')` to something other than `s` in the first snippet?

Comment: @jwodder the idea is that there would be other code between the snippets. I was just showing how to convert something to unicode or bytes if you don't know the existing type.